# how to give access to limited and specific users to use my PHP web application

Tags: php, mysql, iis, server

I have a web based software application developed in PHP/Mysql running on Windows IIS Server, I want to give access to limited and specific users to my application. I tried to keep a encrypted file and read it through Javascript, but Chrome deny access that file without server installation, any other perfect and proper idea is needed.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a linux hosting a dirty and fast solution could be to add an .htaccess file.

here a complete guide:

http://www.htaccess-guide.com/password-protection/

Comment: Emphasis on dirty, but it is fast.